# How to track event (click on phone number) in Google Analytics for Joomla 3.9?

Tags: google-analytics, joomla3.0

I tried several methods to track phone call event in Google Analytics, but without success.

In the moment I've used: `ga('send', 'event', 'Phone Call Tracking', 'Click to Call', '0884344644', 0);`

Here is the and screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWEuy.jpg

This code does not send an event in Google Analytics. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **gtag** tracking code (not *ga*), so to measure Google Analytics events you need to use the appropriate syntax:

```
gtag('event', 'Click to Call', {
  'event_category': 'Phone Call Tracking',
  'event_label': '0884344644',
  'value': 0
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events